# The collapse effect is not working- bootstrap

Tags: html, frontend, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I tried to make a button that displays the hidden content when revealed using bootstrap but it's not working. Any Suggestions

```
<button class="bc2 border-primary bg-primary rounded-2 mt-4 p-1 text-nowrap card-footer text-white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ho2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ho2">Get Started</button>
                <div class="collapse" id="ho2">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                       Hello World!
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the data attr to `data-bs-*`(for BS5).
If correct BS js file and css file are included it should work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="bc2 border-primary bg-primary rounded-2 mt-4 p-1 text-nowrap card-footer text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ho2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ho2">Get Started</button>
<div class="collapse" id="ho2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap 5, then:

- change `data-toggle="collapse"` (Bootstrap 4) to `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` and
- change `data-target="#ho2"` (Bootstrap 4) to `data-bs-target="#ho2"`.

Comment: I tried but didn't get the desired result